# Dojo 1.8.3 Amd style too strict

Tags: dojo, amd

I am using DOJO 1.8.3, and my code breaks every time. I keep getting a `parser.parser` error.

Help me understand this: if I use `require(["dojo/some-module"]`, if I load a module once using `require` then we should not use require again to load same module, but if I do, things don't work. Should I only use `parser.parser()` once? Please explain.

Comment: Can you please post your code to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Yes, a code-sample would help.

Answer (score 1):

The module will be defined within the closure defined by `require`. So this is legal:

```js
require(['dojo/some-module'], function(someModule) {
    someModule.someFunction(); //inside the closure scope
});
```

But this is not:

```js
require(['dojo/some-module'], function(someModule) {
    // stuff
});

someModule.someFunction(); //outside the closure scope
```

So if you need to use `parser.parse()`, you need to use it within your `require` function callback:

```js
require(['dojo/parser'], function(parser) {
    parser.parse();
});
```